# AJAX replace content in DIV not by ID or class

Tags: ajax, replace

Can some one help me..
I have a script who generates code like this >>

```
<div id="imageok">img1.png</div>
<div id="imageok">img22.jpg</div>
<div id="imageok">img333.gif</div>
```

In AJAX the name of the image is called imgname its equal to content of the div.

I want to replace the text inside the div but I can't use the id because its the same for each div.. I tried to search for div by it content (I have the name of the image in the AJAX)

Perhaps its something like..
 GET element where content =="img1.png" > replace 
I just can't write it correct..

Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do can be accomplished more 'neatly' with jQuery.

Have you used jQuery before? If yes, then you can do something like this:

```
// get content into a variable called 'result'
$('div').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).text() == 'img1.png') {
    $(this).text(result);
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Another question, if I try to change it with code (from name I want to make it to a img) its changing to a visual code not to working html (as its displaying instead img1.png to display  <img src="img1.png"  ) Can I set it to display it not as text but as html working code (in this case like image)

Comment: Yes you can do that like so:
$(this).text('<img src='+ imgName + '\' />');

Comment: Sorry for my second question.. I just had to replace the .text(result) with .html(result) :)

Comment: Oh I thought you were getting the image URL as 'result'. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Nope. I use AJAX based img upload and after finishing the upload I process the image with some PHP code (rename,resize,thumbs) and at the end PHP returns code which I want to display with AJAX but I got that problem with all same divs now its working correct the name is replaced as it need to be :) 
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Can you help me again.. 
If the name of the image contain a free space the code is not working.. what I can do to fix that ?

Comment: You could iterate over the characters of the returned image name and if you find a space, ignore it else concatenate that character with a "new name". This will remove all the spaces from the name.

There might be better solutions but this is the one I can come up with right now.